# How to plot data from JSON object on pdf canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, 2d

Following is reference code. 
Rendering pdf file on canvas with pdf.js . 
How to plot data on this pdf canvas?
This pdf canvas is something different from image and svg file which is but obvious but never found any documentation for pdf canvas.

```
function pdfCanvas(scale){    
    PDFJS.getDocument('gkhead.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
      // Using promise to fetch the page
      pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
       // var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        //
        // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
        //
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.height = 800;
        //canvas.width = viewport.width;
            canvas.width = 800;


        //
        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        //
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: context,
          viewport: viewport
        };


        page.render(renderContext);


      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with just a regular html canvas. Try taking a look at these resources on how to work with canvas. http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/toc.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas

I haven't used PDFJS but given your sample code I assume that any drawing or graphing you do in the canvas object will show up in your pdf.